# Resizing Bitmap to increase image quality

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have an application that gets and saves a picture of an open window. Unfortunately, when the dimensions of the image and window match, the image quality is unacceptably low. I've increased the size the of the RenderTargetBitmap, which has increased the image quality, however, now the dimensions of the resulting image are too large for my purposes.

My question is this: Is there any way to resize the resulting RenderTargetBitmap to the original dimensions of the window? And is it possible to do this without a corresponding loss in image quality? Here's the code I have now.

```
public static RenderTargetBitmap GetReportImage(Grid view)
    {

    // Increased dimensions to increase image quality
        Size size = new Size(view.ActualWidth * 2, view.ActualHeight * 2 );

    // The dimensions that I want to convert back to.
        _size = new Size(view.ActualWidth, view.ActualHeight); 


        if (size.IsEmpty)
            return null;

        RenderTargetBitmap result = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96 , 96 , PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext context = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            context.DrawRectangle(new VisualBrush(view), null, new Rect(new Point(), size));

            context.Close();
        }

        result.Render(drawingVisual);

    // Can I resize result to _size.Width and _size.Height?  

        return result;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: 200% font size ("retina")?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: Does the "size of the window" map to pixels or are you using font/render-scaling in Windows which means that a width of 1 isn't 1 pixel wide but perhaps 2 (200% scale)?

Comment: I'm not sure, though I know that I never made any intentional use of font-scaling if that helps. Is there some way that I can check for you?

Comment: Check the display settings of your computer, right-click the desktop.

Comment: OK I see. I just looked and I'm using font/render-scaling.

Comment: So then what is the question here? If you have a window on-screen that says it is 640x480 but is in reality 1280x960 pixels in size, and you capture it at 1280x960, isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; it may be that I'm working outside my range here. The issue I'm having is that when I ultimately save the Bitmap `result` as a jpg, the jpg is too blurry/pixelated if I use the `_size` dimensions. Using the `size` dimensions instead takes care of this problem, but then the jpg is too large on the screen. So Ideally I'd like to use the `_size` dimensions to capture the image, and then convert back to `size` without losing much image quality.

Comment: If you are capturing a screenshot pixel-for-pixel but displaying it in something that doesn't take scaling into account then yes, it will differ in size from what you think is the original. If "width" here is scaling-aware so that width=1 means pixels=2, then displaying the 640x480 (width*height) image taken at 1280x960 (pixels*pixels) in an area that is 1280x960 (width*height) will double the size. You need to take the scaling into account if you want to do this.

Comment: I tried calling this `drawingVisual.Transform = new ScaleTransform(_size.Width, _size.Height);` before rendering the result, but the jpg was just one solid color. Do you think ScaleTransform might get what I'm after with some further work?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't use WPF so I can't say but the question just reminded me of someone else asking the same thing, why taking a screenshot of a 640x480 image ended up with a image file of 1280x960 in size.

Comment: That (int) cast should have made you go "hmm".  Google "wpf convert inches to pixels".

Answer (score 0):

To resize back you can do:

```
var resized = new TransformedBitmap(bmp,
    new ScaleTransform(newWidth / bmp.PixelWidth, newHeight / bmp.PixelHeight));
```

You can also try to scale both dimensions and dpi, like this:

```
public static RenderTargetBitmap RenderBitmap(FrameworkElement visualToRender, double scale) {
        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap
            (
            (int) (scale*(visualToRender.ActualWidth + 1)),
            (int) (scale*(visualToRender.ActualHeight + 1)),
            scale*96,
            scale*96,
            PixelFormats.Pbgra32
            );
        bmp.Render(visualToRender);
        return bmp;
    }
```

Updated to answer your comment. So I suppose you need to save the result somewhere, probably to jpeg or png. Both RenderTargetBitmap and TransformedBitmap inherit from BitmapSource, so both you can encode to image like this:

```
var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
using (Stream s = File.Create("test.png")) {
    encoder.Save(s);
}
```

Here "bmp" can be both RenderTargetBitmap and TrasnformedBitmap

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I'm having some trouble implementing it yet. I'm trying the first approach, however, it's returning a `TransformedBitmap`, while what I need is a `RenderTargetBitmap` (which is the original format of `result`). Any idea what I should try next?

Comment: Updated to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks! This put my final jpg in the dimensions I want, but I ended up losing the quality gains of capturing the image in the higher dimensions. Is there any way to resize my image without losing so much of the quality? (It becomes distractingly blurry and pixelated.) I've also tried adding `encoder.QualityLevel = 100; ` but this doesn't seem to have a noticeable effect, apart from increasing the file size.

Comment: Did you try first advice of scaling not only dimensions but dpi, using example code?

Comment: Ok, I just tried using the RenderBitmap method to scale both the dimensions and the dpi, but now the result is the dimensions I want, but only showing the top left corner of the image.